# YOLOv7 --save-txt Argument Path Change

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, yolo

I do object detection with YOLOv7 ready model. I'm running [detect.py](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/detect.py) like this "python detect.py --source human.jpg --save-txt"

The --save-txt argument gives me the coordinates in the form of .txt
and it saves to 'runs/detect/exp/labels'
but I want it to save in 'runs/data/train'

I think the relevant code is on line 108, but I couldn't give the file path I wanted.

```
txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')  # img.txt
```

I tried this but I couldn't set the name:

```
txt_path = 'runs/data/train'  # img.txt
```

Anyone who knows how to change the txt_path variable can help?

Answer (score 0):

not a very professional solution but it worked

```
img_name = p.name.split(".")
txt_path =  f'runs/data/train/{img_name[0]}' # img.txt
```